# I want to show a file in an AppleScript bundle, but shell returns: file not found

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, textedit

My Bundle File: `reference.txt`

My Code:

```
set bashFile to path to resource "reference.txt"
set the reference_data to do shell script "type " & quoted form of (POSIX path of bashFile)
display dialog reference_data
```

shell returns:

```
type: file not found (but the file exists)
```

How i can show this file on a dialog (or in TextEdit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type` shell builtin is used to see how it's arguments would be interpreted as a command.

Try replacing `type` with `cat` and see if that does what you expect.

Comment: I create apps for MS-DOS, too. I'm confused with MS-DOS programming. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Jay said : `cat` instead of `type` work :

```
set bashFile to path to resource "reference.rtf" 
set the reference_data to do shell script "cat " & quoted form of (POSIX path of bashFile)
display dialog reference_data
```

But displaying it in a popup my not be very convenient.

```
set bashFile to path to resource "arguing.pdf"
tell application "Finder"
    open file bashFile
end tell
```

This code will open the file with the default app defined in the Finder.